# foreach loop with array_combine

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have changed a for-loop into a foreach loop with `array_combine` for using two arrays in this foreach.

Unfortunately it look like array_combine will just get only unique value, but I need to combine all parts of value-groups like:

example:

```
$number = array (1,2,3,4,5,6);   
//$array = array ('a','a','b','c','d','e');   

 $array2=   array ( 
            array ('a','a','b','c','d','e'),
            array ('a','a','b','c','d','e')
                 );     

foreach (array_combine($array[0], $number) as $array2 => $number2)  {

    echo $number2 . $array2 . "<br>";
}
```

desired output

```
1a  (this result is missing)
2a
3b
4c
5d
6e
```

Edit:
One of my $array should be a 2-dimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, because you use `$array` as keys of your combined array and each key has to be unique, so the last one with the same key will be in your array. The other ones, will get deleted ([Simple example to reproduce](http://3v4l.org/NRkpY)).

To solve your problem you could use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and pass both arrays as arguments to loop through them:

```
array_map(function($v1, $v2){
    echo $v1 . $v2 . "<br>";
}, $number, $array);
```

output:

```
1a
2a
3b
4c
5d
6e
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/376541)

Comment: Correct `amp`  top `map`

Comment: @splash58 Thank you for your demo. I think I have another problem, because in my real code $array is a 2-dimensional array. I have tried to use this system and I think because of the [1] it don't worked. my old code and with array_map: https://eval.in/376545

Comment: @Grischa Then add your **real** array structure to your question

Comment: @splash58 Ok, sorry I didn't know this would be such a difference.

Comment: @Grischa Then just change the last codeline of my code in my answer from: `}, $number, $array);` to: `}, $number, $array[0]);`

Comment: @splash58 Why isn't  my new code not working (see the link) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79844/discussion-between-grischa-and-rizier123).

Comment: @Grischa Because you don't have to change the function head and what you did is also completely wrong in terms of syntax. Just change out the last line as described above ^

Answer (score 1):

You can't duplicate keys in an array, but you can simulate duplicate keys with Generators if you're running PHP > 5.5.0

```
$number = array (1,2,3,4,5,6);   
$array = array ('a','a','b','c','d','e');   

function myCombinedArray($keys, $values) {
    foreach($values as $index => $value) {
        yield $keys[$index] => $value;
    }
}

foreach (myCombinedArray($array, $number) as $array2 => $number2)  {

    echo $number2 . $array2 . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately my hoster changed only from PHP 5.3 to 5.4. some months ago. Did you see my Edit on the question? (One of my $array should be a 2-dimensional array)